# How to solve differential equation for cylindrical diffusion?

Tags: differential-equations, laplace-transform

How the differential equation for diffusion along a hollow cylinder,

$$ \frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = D \Biggl(\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial \phi^2}\ + \frac{\partial^2 c} {\partial z^2}\Biggl)$$

can be solved by Laplace transform using common boundaries. The concentration gradient is only along the `z` direction, but obviously, the diffusion is not one-dimensional due to the cylindrical medium.